# How to fix this PHP loop?

Tags: php, loops

```
this is what i want.
123456
 23456
  3456
   456
    56
     6
```

Hi, i have trouble with this loop.

```
    <?php
    for ($x = 7; $x >= 1; $x--) {
        for ($y = 7; $y > $x; $y--) {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp";
        }
        $s = 7;
        while ($s < $x) {

            $f++;
            $s--;
        }

        for ($f=1; $f < 7; $f++) {
            echo "$f";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

this is what i got. I want to get the $f work but it is ignoring it.

Comment: a better question would include your desired output

Comment: i  dont think you need 4 loops

Comment: Why don't you just take the starting string and remove the first character from the string?

Comment: I see 2 dimensions, right and down, yet I count 4 loops. Can be done with just 2, just saying..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it simpler than you did.

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 6; $x++) {

    for($y = 1; $y <=6; $y++){ 
        if($x > $y)
            echo "&nbsp&nbsp;";
        else
            echo $y;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

With x you control the lines and with y the columns. If the lines is greater than the column you print the spaces, and if not, the number.